The WebSocket handshake Connection field is missing the upgrade token
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main(){

    auto const address = boost::asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1");
    auto const port = static_cast<unsigned short>(std::atoi("8083"));

    boost::asio::io_context ioc{1};
    tcp::acceptor acceptor{ioc,{address,port}};

    while(1){
        tcp::socket socket{ioc};
        acceptor.accept(socket);
        std::cout<<"socket accepted"<<std::endl; 

        std::thread{[q = std::move(socket)]() mutable {

            boost::beast::websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws {std::move(q)};
            ws.accept();

            while(1){
                boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;

                ws.read(buffer);

                auto out = boost::beast::buffers_to_string(buffer.cdata());
                std::cout<<out<<std::endl;
            }

        }}.detach();
    }

    return 0;
}

this is my code, and it is giving me this error => The WebSocket handshake Connection field is missing the upgrade token
please help me to resolve it.
I read some article where someone said you can try after changing your browser but still facing the same issue.

The connecting client is not correctly sending the websocket upgrade request.
A valid request looks like
GET /path HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8083
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: vWJaQvnm4qm1AUccLfSmBw==

The unit tests show what kind of a request prompts the error you showed, e.g.
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Server: beast
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13

As you can see the Connection header has the wrong value. I tested your code using websocat and it works fine. Check that your client doesn't accidentally expect a HTTP server or uses WSS (secure websockets).


Slightly simplified/cleaned up code I used for the test: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95ba31daf1e6c035
